# Explanation of solving intersection of two planes

Tags: calculus

I understand that in order to solve for intersection line of two planes, you must find the cross product of the normal vectors of each plane which will be parallel to the line of intersection. That makes sense to me.

What I cannot figure out is why I cannot just find the intersection line by treating the two planes like a system of equations and solving. This seems reasonable as it is the way you solve the intersection of two lines in 2 dimensional space. Any explanation to help me understand the fault in my logic is much appreciated.

Comment: I think that works just fine.